# No interaction posible after css card flip animation

Tags: html, css, animation

ok so i'm creating a `form`  so that when the user  clicks on the `register` link, the form does a `transform: rotateY(180)`,  now  the flip is done correctly but  i have no interactivity with the other side of the form, and can´t figure a solution for this, is suppose its because ther is a container  that wraps both forms and this container is the one that does the  animation,  so  is there a solution for this ? any tips apreciated thanks, here's the code: 
html->

```
<div id="reg-login-wrapper" >
<div id="flip">
    <div id="login">
        <input type="text"  class="inputs" name="user-login"  id="user-login"placeholder="Name"/>
        <br /><input type="password" class="inputs" name="pas-login"  id="pas-login" placeholder="Password"/>
        <label  for="keep-loged">Keep me loged in</label>&nbsp; 
         <input type="checkbox" id="loged" name="keep-loged"/>           
        <br /><input type="button" value="Submit"  onClick="javascript: validateUser();"/>
        <span id="forgot-password">Forgot your username/password ?</span>
        <br /><span id="go-register">Register</span>
    </div><!-- end #login -->
 <div id="register">
        <input type="text" name="user-reg" placeholder="Name"/>
        <input type="email"  name="email-reg" placeholder="E-mail"/>
        <input type="password" name="pwd-reg"  placeholder="Password"/>
        <input type="password" name="pwd-confirm-reg"  placeholder="Confirm password"/>
        <input type="text"  name="date-reg" value="<?php echo date("M-d-Y");?>" id="reg-date"  disabled />
        <input type="button" value="Submit" />
  </div> <!-- end #register-->
</div><!-- end # reg-login-wrapper -->               
      </div> <!-- end # reg-login-wrapper -->
```

css:

```
.flip2reg{
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
#register{
position: absolute;
border: none;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 500px;
height: 400px;
margin: 0px auto;
background: rgb(63,13,25);
padding-top: 30px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px black;
-webkit-border-radius: 50px 0 100px 0;
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
backface-visibility: hidden;
z-index: 1;
}
#login{
position: absolute;
border: none;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 500px;
height: 275px;
margin: 0 auto;
background: rgb(63,13,25);
padding-top: 70px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px black;
-webkit-border-radius: 50px 0 100px 0;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
backface-visibility: hidden;
z-index: 3;
}

#reg-login-wrapper{
border: none;
width: 500px;
height: 400px;
margin: 2% auto;
perspective: 1000;
}
```

and the  .js that  activates the animation:

```
$("#go-register").click(function(){                     
                            $("#flip").addClass('flip2reg');

                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so figured out this issue and solved it adding some css after the animation was done:

```
$("#go-register").click(function(){                     
                            $("#flip").addClass('flip2reg').css({"backface-visibility": "visible", "z-index": "-1"});
                            $("#login").css({"backface-visibility": "hidden", "z-index": "-1"});
                            $("#register").css("z-index", "900");                       
                    });
```